# Regex to match all lines starting with a specific string

Tags: regex, groovy

I have this very long cfg file, where I need to find the latest occurrence of a line starting with a specific string. An example of the cfg file:

```
...
# format: - search.index.[number] = [search field]:element.qualifier
...    
search.index.1 = author:dc.contributor.*
...
search.index.12 = language:dc.language.iso
...
jspui.search.index.display.1 = ANY
...
```

I need to be able to get the last occurrence of the line starting with `search.index.[number]` , more specific: I need that number. For the above snippet, that number would be **12**.

As you can see, there are other lines too containing that pattern, but I do **not** want to match those.

I'm using Groovy as a programming/scripting language.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I bet there's something like "lastIndexOf()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
def m = lines =~ /(?m)^search\.index\.(\d+)/
m[ -1 ][ 1 ]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!
P.S. Maybe you could clarify your answer a bit more? It works, but it's a little unclear to me why.

Comment: The `(?m)` tells Groovy to do a multi-line regular expression match, then the `m[-1]` tells it to get the last match, and `[ 1 ]` gets the first group from that last match.  So in your example, `m[0][1]` is the first match `1` and `m[-1][1]` will be the last match `12`

Comment: Thanks for that. Maybe some more info for others regarding the regex:
`^` says it's at the beginning of the line, `(\d+)` makes sure a number follows `search.index.`.

Comment: Suddenly when I run this code again, I get the following error: `index is out of range 0..-1 (index = -1)` Any idea why?

Comment: @Dreamonic it's not finding a match. so `search.index.` doesn't exist in the text

Comment: The strange thing is I haven't changed the file. `search.index.` still exists! The file reference is right too, everything stayed the same as when it did work...

Comment: @Dreamonic something must have changed... Otherwise it would still work ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should go for it but...
If you can do a multi-line search (anyway you have to here), the only way would be to read the file backward. So first, eat everything with a `.*` (om nom nom)(if you can make the dot match all, `(?:.|\s)*` if you can't). Now match your pattern `search\.index\.(\d+)`. And you want to match this pattern at the beginning of a line: `(?:^|\n)` (hoping you're not using some crazy format that doesn't use `\n` as new line character).

So...

```
(?:.|\s)*(?:^|\n)search\.index\.(\d+)
```

The number should be in the 1st matching group. ([Test in **JavaScript**](http://jsfiddle.net/P5zgq/))

PS: I don't know groovy, so sorry if it's totally not appropriate.

**Edit:**
This should also work:

```
search\.index\.(\d+)(?!(?:.|\s)*?(?:^|\n)search\.index\.\d+)
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reply! 

I'm trying out your regex in a slightly altered version, looking like `(?:^|\n)search\.index\.(\d+)` (because the full version gave a StackOverflowError). Seems like it works! Just needs some adjustments for my purposes.

Thank you very much (for the answer + explanation)!

Comment: @Dreamonic that was more just for information than anything. I found it funny that you can do it with one regex by "hacking" the system ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your expression :

```
^search\.index\.(\d+)/
```

And then with Groovy you can get your result with:

```
 matcher[0][0]
```

[Here is an explanation page.](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+5+-+Capturing+regex+groups)

Comment: That won't match anything as it's not in multiline mode.  And if it did match (if `search.index.1 = author:dc.contributor.*` was on the first line), it would return `'search.index.1'`, and not the number that is being searched for by the group

Comment: For some reason, that link to the groovy.codehaus.org is broken. Newer link http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html seems to indicate a bunch of the regex to be "Deprecated" ...still seeking a definitive answer.